# Angular 4 - Firebase - Check if the user is connected

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase for the authentification with Google. But the problem is when I'm connected and I refresh the page, I would like to get the Session/CurrentUser.
In the documentation I have to use that :

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    console.log(user)
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

This function works but the problem is I don't know how tu use an observable to wait the end of this function. Because this function is similar to an ajax function, and angular doesn't wait so if I set the user in a local variable, it will be null.

I already searched in stackoverflow and I didn't find a solution

Thank you

Comment: You can use firebase.auth().currentUser to see if it's already connected for starters. If you want to use onAuthStateChanged, what do you want to have happen afterwards? Can't you put the rest inside the if (user) block?

Comment: Take a look at angularfire2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this My Answer combined with @wandrille 's solution :

You can use `Subject` instead `Observable` like this :

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";

class AuthService{
   public connectionSubject : Subject<string>() = new Subject<string>();

   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
     if (user) {
       console.log(user)
       this.connectionSubject.next({ state : "connected", user});
     } else {
       this.connectionSubject.next("disconnected");
     }
   });


}
```

in Your component :

```
 @Component({
   //... 
  })
  class YourComponent{
      constructor(private authService: AuthService){
      }
      ngOnInit(){
         this.authService.connectionSubject.subscribe((data) => {
            if(data.state === 'connected'){
              console.log(data.user);
            }else{
               //...
            }
         });
      }
  }
```

Comment: In your example the variable user will content the user. But how can I return this user in my controller ? I want to control if the user is connected and if it doesn't I want to restric him some routes

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use angularFire2:

You can create a service for your Auth systeme.

some example:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  public firebaseUser : Observable < firebase.User >;
  public currentUser : firebase.User;

  constructor(public afAuth : AngularFireAuth) {

    this.firebaseUser = this.afAuth.authState

  }

  isAuthentificated() {
    return this.firebaseUser
  }

  getCurrentUSer() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser
  }

  loginUser({email, password}){...some code...}
}
```

And you have just to call *getCurrentUSer()* or *isAuthentificated()* in your component.

Comment: I use angularFire2. Your method is working but the problem is I want to check if the currentUser isn't null in the controller. But if I do that in the controller, the curent user is always null